# Expected type 'Iterable[SupportsLessThan | Any]' (matched generic type 'Iterable[SupportsLessThanT]'), got 'object' instead

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, sorting, pycharm

The two following blocks of code should be equivalent:

##### Block 1

```
array_1 = [[12, 15], [10, 1], [5, 13]]

print(array_1)
""" output:
[[12, 15], [10, 1], [5, 13]]
"""

print(sorted(array_1))
""" output:
[[5, 13], [10, 1], [12, 15]]
"""
```

---

##### Block 2

```
import numpy as np

np_array_1 = np.array([[12, 15], [10, 1], [5, 13]])

print(np_array_1)
""" output:
[[12 15]
 [10  1]
 [ 5 13]]
"""

array_1 = np_array_1.tolist()

print(array_1)
""" output:
[[12, 15], [10, 1], [5, 13]]
"""

print(sorted(array_1))
""" output:
[[5, 13], [10, 1], [12, 15]]
"""
```

---

##### But, in PyCharm, if I use:

```
sorted(np_array_1.tolist())  # SEE BLOCK 2
```

I receive this only ***warning***, but apparently without any issue:

```
Expected type 'Iterable[SupportsLessThan | Any]' (matched generic type 'Iterable[SupportsLessThanT]'), got 'object' instead
```

I would like to get clean code, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in PyCharm.

Please see:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-45958/Type-error-sorting-Iterable-of-dataclassorderTrue-instances

[image]

Comment: Thank you, @GodisOne, for sharing it. Good to know that should not be a problem of my code. So, you say that the code should be ok and that I have to do nothing, isn't it?

Comment: @RiccardoVolpe yes your code is perfect.. it is a PyCharm issue.